# Why do I get error when using class_weight in sklearn GridsearchCV SVM?

Tags: python, class, scikit-learn, svm, weighted

Below is my code:

```
tuned_parameters = [
    {'kernel': ['linear], 'C':[1, 10], 'class_weight': ['auto']}, {'kernel': ['rbf'], 'C':[1,10], 'class_weight':['auto']}]
clf = GridSearchCV(svm.SVC(), tuned_parameters, cv=5, scoring='accuracy')
clf.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/arajabi/PycharmProjects/Muffin/classification.py", line 77, in <module>
    clf3.fit(x_train, y_train)
  File "/home/arajabi/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 639, in fit
    cv.split(X, y, groups)))
  File "/home/arajabi/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 779, in __call__
    while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "/home/arajabi/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 625, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "/home/arajabi/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 588, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
  File "/home/arajabi/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 111, in apply_async
    result = ImmediateResult(func)
  File "/home/arajabi/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 332, in __init__
    self.results = batch()
  File "/home/arajabi/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 131, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/home/arajabi/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 131, in <listcomp>
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/home/arajabi/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 458, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "/home/arajabi/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 150, in fit
    y = self._validate_targets(y)
  File "/home/arajabi/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 502, in _validate_targets
    self.class_weight_ = compute_class_weight(self.class_weight, cls, y_)
  File "/home/arajabi/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/class_weight.py", line 62, in compute_class_weight
    " got: %r" % class_weight)
ValueError: class_weight must be dict, 'balanced', or None, got: 'auto'
```

I am relatively new to python. Can someone give me a straightforward solution for this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation of sklearn.svm.SVC is right [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html).
Parameter `class_weight` doesn't accept 'auto' as an input value. That is your error.

You can solve this by replacing:

```
'class_weight': ['auto']
```

with:

```
'class_weight': ['balanced']
```

Comment: The only place I disagree with your answer is that the replacement for `auto` in this case (the default behavior) is `None`, rather than `'Balanced'`

Comment: @G.Anderson But I'm reading in "http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html"  that: "The “balanced” mode uses the values of y to automatically adjust weights inversely proportional to class frequencies in the input data"

Comment: This is true, I think it's pretty open to interpretation what the OP actually intended. I interpreted the user's original intent to use the default behavior, you interpreted it to use automatic class balancing. `None` "automatically" uses the classes as they are, `'Balanced'` "automatically" balances the classes. That's probably why they didn't use `'auto'` as the keyword, lol.

Answer (score 1):

You passed in an [invalid parameter](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html), `'auto'` for the SVC. The error message tells you what the possible values are: a dict of your classes, balanced, or None. If you want it to use the default behavior, leave it blank or enter `None`

`class_weight : {dict, ‘balanced’}, optional`

Generally when I gridsearch a SVC, I use `'class_weight': [None, 'Balanced]` unless I have a specific class balance I want to try

Answer (score 0):

This is not a typical Python error, it is GridSearchCV which does not like your `auto` argument in class_weight:

```
tuned_parameters = [
{'kernel': ['linear], 'C':[1, 10], 'class_weight': ['auto' <---
```

I'am not familiar with, I can only repeat what the error message says:

```
class_weight must be dict, 'balanced', or None, got: 'auto'
```

For more infos, you have to look at http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.